# Loading different elf on qemu arm cores

Tags: qemu

I'm using QEMU-4.1.0 aarch64 to emulate some multi-core systems. Is it possible to run different elfs on different cores?

I am trying to use qemu provided function arm_load_kernel (
**https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/arm/boot.c** line:1275) during my board initialization, but am not able to load different elfs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load more than one ELF file then you should look at the 'generic loader' documented in docs/generic-loader.txt. This also lets you specify which CPU, if any, should have its PC set to the entry point of the ELF file. Depending on the board, you might be able to load all the ELF files that way and not specify -kernel at all. The command line for it is '-device loader,[options...]'.

Note that if you are using a board model which starts with most of the CPUs in a 'power off' state (ie where the expectation is that the primary CPU will power the other CPUs on) then you'll need to have code to do that whether you have one ELF or several (or, if the board permits it, use suitable command line options to have all the CPUs start powered on).